# Subtotal average, of data linked to a particular month in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a large spreadsheet and I am struggling to get an average, no formula I have used thus far from google or otherwise, has worked.

The average is an average of time, in particular, hours between a start and end time, converted into days.

- In column E9:E1833, I have start time as dd/mm/yyy hh:mm
- In column J9:J1833, I have the time in days, from start to finish as [h]:mm (some are empty)
- I have an auto filter setup to change with job type / area / status etc, and the result needs to change as data is filtered.

The following formula works, but does not recalculate:

`{=AVERAGE(IF(MONTH(E9:E1833)=1,(J9:J1833)))}`

The following formula works, but gives an incorrect result:

`=AVERAGE(IF(MONTH(E1833)=1,SUBTOTAL(101,(J9:J1833))))`

I have tried Offset, with similar results, and many of the "off-the-shelf" solutions produces `#Div/0`, `#REF`, `#Value` or fail to allow the entry altogether.

Any help would be much appreciated, preferably not in VBA, as I don't want to be lumbered with this spreadsheet forever. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many years of data do you have?

Comment: The earliest entry that I have to work with is 2005, all the way through to present day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are going to be filtering, and want the result to change as you filter, just use the `AGGREGATE` function:

```
=AGGREGATE(1,3,J:J)
```

**EDIT**:  *Animation added in response to question*

The values in the Values column can be times, although you may have to format the result of the `AGGREGATE` function (cell/numberformat) to show the result as `[h]:mm`

*Note:  GIF will play twice.  To repeat, refresh the page*

[image]

Comment: Could you show me how this would work the average out if the month in E9:E1833 matches?

Comment: @AlexanderRhodes What happened when you tried it?  If you filter the column (you wrote you had an autofilter), the result of the function will adjust.  Read HELP for the `AGGREGATE` function to see how it works.

Comment: @AlexanderRhodes I have added an animation to show how it works.

Comment: I see you are using the filter to gain a result. I require a method that outputs each result (per month) in H3:S3 so that I may reference this on a dashboard. Hence why the original formulas contained the month query. As such, the formula would need to be replicated 12 times per sheet, and for the number of rows per sheet. I have a dashboard on another sheet that will reference this result, to gain a trend that can be seen at a glance. 

Filter wise, I will need to filter the type of job, area, status on each sheet as needed, and then be able to glance at the dashboard to note changes.

Comment: @AlexanderRhodes  I guess I don't know what you want. You wrote that *the result needs to change as data is filtered*.  If you want to get the results in a table by month, just use a Pivot Table, and have a worksheet_change triggered Event macro to do the refresh.

Comment: @AlexanderRhodes I'm sorry but, for me, repeating what you wrote before does not add clarity.

Comment: The result I am after is: Jan=8.13, Feb=13.11,Mar=49.13, Apr=12.55 etc. 
This result would change if I go from all work, to only looking at an oil change, rather than including tyre change as an example. 

I need to be able to output this data to a dashboard, to get an idea of trends. 
I need to be able to filter between jobs, status of a job, etc.
I need the result to output the resulting  cell that tallies the month. 

I have looked at Pivot tables, and these also suffer from not updating automatically.

Comment: What I really want is: =AVERAGE(IF(MONTH(E9:E1833)=1,(J9:J1833))) as a format that will update when I filter job type / status etc. Yet nothing below degree level excel has worked thus far.

Comment: @AlexanderRhodes My first thought is that you are going to need a VBA solution to do all that.  Write a VBA macro that will fire when you filter the table; process the visible rows; and then write that result to your results table area.

Comment: My knowledge doesn't extended as far as VBA, do you have any sources of information that might help me?

Comment: @AlexanderRhodes That's out of the scope of this group.  But I'd probably start with an Excel VBA for Dummies book.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula seems to work.

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(SUBTOTAL(9,(OFFSET(J9:J1833,ROW(J9:J1833)-MIN(ROW(J9:J1833)),0,1)))>0,(IF(MONTH(E9:E1833)=3,SUBTOTAL(9,(OFFSET(J9:J1833,ROW(J9:J1833)-MIN(ROW(J9:J1833)),0,1)))))))}
```

The `SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET` part of the function returns an array where filtered numbers are 0, and visible numbers return their values. If you just averaged that array, you would get the wrong number because you would be averaging all those zeros. So the `IF` statement just creates an array that returns a `FALSE` for zero, which is not averaged.

An additional caution that gave me a headache as I was playing around, was you are also filtering on `MONTH()=1`. The issue with that is, blank cells return a January date, which means they will not be filtered by `MONTH()=1`

Comment: This result returns the same result for every month, which doesn't match the result I have for =AVERAGE(IF(MONTH(E9:E1833)=1,(J9:J1833))).

Comment: Changing the month statement to an embedded if statement seems to correct this problem. Answer reflects these changes.

Comment: This works, to a degree. I have managed to find a formula that works with 2 extra helper columns, and this matches my manual calculation check. However this formula, for an unknown reason, is out by a little. 8.13 became 8.82, 15.15 became 15.83 and 49.13 became 52.75 and so on. 

Well done for getting close though, there isn't any easy answer to get it done right, and with 2 extra helper columns it did take some time to get things going.