# Excel 2017 Formula - Average data by month, while being filterable

Tags: filter, excel-formula, average, subtotal, monthcalendar

I'm not a VBA coder, and I would prefer an excel formula if possible, the easiest solution will be the best one.

[Test workbook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmiZD.png)

As you can see, I have plenty of columns, which are filterable.

I am attempting to retrieve an average of Column L, but I want the data to be calculated for the correct month in G3:R3.

The resulting calculation needs to be recalculated when filtered, between customers, sites, status, job type etc.

I am referencing the resulting cells in another sheet, which gives an idea of trends I can glance at, as such filtering by month in each sheet, is not an option.

```
=AVERAGE(IF(MONTH(E9:E1833)=1,(J9:J1833)))
```

This one does not update with the filtered data.

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH(E9:E1833)=1,J9:J1833,0)) /SUM(IF(MONTH(E9:E1833)=1,1))
```

This one does not update with the filtered data.

I have tried 5 different SUBTOTAL formulas, some with OFFSET, none of these produce the same result I get when checking manually.

Each worksheet has over 1,500 hundred rows, the largest is 29148 rows. The data goes back as far as 2005.

Please can someone help me find a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtotal average, of data linked to a particular month in Excel 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630765/subtotal-average-of-data-linked-to-a-particular-month-in-excel-2016)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a helper column which returns `1` if the row is visible and returns `0` if the row is invisible (or blank). This allows a bit more freedom in your formulas.

For example, if you want to create a helper column in column `X`, type this into cell `X9` and drag down:

```
= SUBTOTAL(103,A9)
```

Now you can create a custom average formula, for example:

```
= SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(E9:E1833)=1)*(X9:X1833)*(J9:J1833))/
  SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(E9:E1833)=1)*(X9:X1833))
```

Not exactly pretty but it gets the job done. (Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing this formula.)

With even more helper columns you could avoid `SUMPRODUCT` altogether and just accomplish this by doing a single `AVERAGEIFS`.

For example if you type into cell `Y9` and drag down:

```
= MONTH(E9)
```

Then your formula could be:

```
= AVERAGEIFS(J9:J1833,X9:X1833,1,Y9:Y1833,1)
```

There isn't a clean way to do this without at least one helper function (if you want to avoid VBA).

Comment: Thank you!

The SUMPRODUCT formula returned #DIV/0!, not sure why.

The AVERAGEIFS formula works like a dream. Thank you!

Comment: It will return `#DIV/0!` if the denominator returns 0. Only way this could happen in the formula above would be if no visible rows have a date in the `E` column in the month of January.

Comment: Also possible that you need to enter it as an array formula. (Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter on the keyboard instead of just Enter after typing the formula.) I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I did try it as an array, and got the same error, not sure why, the averageifs solution works well though, each month comes out the same as a manual calculation, with and without filtered data, so now to repeat for 6 more worksheets :)

Comment: Not sure why the `SUMPRODUCT` formula isn't working, but probably not a bad thing to use the `AVERAGEIFS` way, just requires one more helper column.